# multi part identifier could not be bound sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I get multipart can not be bound error on following query

```
update nfltx
set 
b.boxno = a.boxno,
b.message = a.message,
b.nameboxno = a.nameboxno,
b.namemsg = a.namemsg,
b.phoneboxno = a.phoneboxno,
b.phonemsg = a.phonemsg

FROM ofltx a JOIN nfltx b 
ON a.ls_fullnam = b.ls_fullnam
```

but if i remove b from boxno message and all i do not get the error . What is the reason behind this. Thank You using sql server 2008

Comment: Use the table alias you have given for `nfltx` (`AS b`) in the `update` section. This should resolve the issue. i think this occurs when you mix table names and there prospective aliases...

Comment: @Killercam - You mean write the query as UPDATE nfltx AS b SET...? I believe that is not allowed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A table alias specified in a FROM clause cannot be used as a qualifier in SET column_name. This is not valid:

```
update nfltx
set 
b.boxno = a.boxno,
b.message = a.message,
b.nameboxno = a.nameboxno,
b.namemsg = a.namemsg,
b.phoneboxno = a.phoneboxno,
b.phonemsg = a.phonemsg

FROM ofltx a JOIN nfltx b 
ON a.ls_fullnam = b.ls_fullnam
```

To make it work, remove the b. alias from the column name.

```
update nfltx
set 
boxno = a.boxno,
message = a.message,
nameboxno = a.nameboxno,
namemsg = a.namemsg,
phoneboxno = a.phoneboxno,
phonemsg = a.phonemsg

FROM ofltx a JOIN nfltx b 
ON a.ls_fullnam = b.ls_fullnam
```

Raj

Comment: is there any official documenation that refers to these sort of conventions?

Answer (score 9):

> What is the reason behind this?

An `UPDATE` (and `DELETE`, `INSERT`) can affect one, and only one, table. You've already identified which table you want to affect here:

```
update nfltx
```

Therefore, it doesn't make *sense* to allow an alias for the left hand side of assignments in the `SET` clause. They *must* be columns belonging to the previously identified table.

If the same table is included in the `FROM` clause multiple times (and it's the table you wish to update), you would need to provide an alias to indicate which instance of the table is to be updated - but you'd provide it (once) in the `UPDATE` clause rather than in the `SET` clause.

Comment: I like your answer more because you explained why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
update b
```

instead of

```
update nfltx
```

Man you guys make things too difficult for those that are learning.