# SQL Server multi-part identifier '%1' could not be bound with INSERTED pseudo-table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, identifier

The situation : I'm writing an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on a table, so I can access to `INSERTED` pseudo-table, if I have good memory. The trigger is a bit long, so I can't copy / pasta it here, but basically, I'd like to compare the datas of the row I'm inserting (representing a good) with the rows of another table (very similar, representing the wishes), in order to determine if the good inserted corresponds to someone's wishes.

So, I almost finished my trigger, but an error occurred. At a given point, I wrote :

```
-- Create and open a cursor
IF (@variable1 = INSERTED.MyField)
BEGIN
    -- some code
END

-- Deallocate and close my cursor
```

But I have the following error :

> The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.MyField" could not be bound

I thought I could do it, as there is only one line in `INSERTED` as this moment (I'm right, don't I ?), but it seems I can't.

Can someone explain me why I'm wrong ?

PS : Yes, I've seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314134/the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989401/the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound-again), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621981/multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound-sql), but they all have a problem with `JOIN`, and I don't have any `JOIN` in here

Comment: Ok first inserted can have more than one value in it, so how can you compare the value to a scalar variable. And you should not ever use a cursor ina trigger as they have to be performant or you will have blocking.

Comment: `INSERTED` can have more than one line, but I'm not inserting data in bulk, so I hop there can be only one line... False ?
And if it's a bad practice to have a cursor, can you suggest me another way to compare the data of the inserted line with datas of another table ? A simple request doesn't seem to be an appropriate solution

Comment: Use joins. You can never guarantee that only one record at a time is inserted. It is dangerous and irresponsible to assumet hat.

Comment: So, I have to join the `INSERTED` table and the table where I'm inserting data, right ?

Answer (score -1):

That error indicates SQL is trying to read 'INSERTED' as an alias for another table

```
IF (@variable1 = INSERTED.MyField)
```

Try the following to reference the inserted table

```
IF (@variable1 = MyField from inserted)
```

Using the inserted and deleted Tables:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

This fixes the syntax and answers the question of why the error is occurring, but comparing inserted to a scalar variable is not recommended. As HLGEM stated, what if you have multiple values in the insert where some match and some don't.

Additionally, Cursors should be a last resort in SQL. In general, cursors are slower and hold up resources.  SQL is a optimized for set-based operations and cursors don't leverage that. Without knowing exactly what you are trying to do in the cursor and how much data you are manipulating, I can't say definitely in this case.

One of the many discussions on StackOverflow about Cursors: [stackoverflow.com/questions/743183/what-is-wrong-with-cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743183/what-is-wrong-with-cursors)

Comment: NEVER suggest comparing the field from insertted to a scalar vaiable. What if you have two records and one matches and one doesn't?

Comment: Yeah, it is not a good idea generally.  The same can be said for cursors most of the time too, which is the first part of that code example.  *If* the inserts are truly need to be one at a time that a cursor would suggest, it *might* work ok, but likely it won't be efficient.

Comment: @AlexB without knowing exactly what you are trying to do in the cursor and how much data you are manipulating, I can't say definitely in this case.  In general, cursors are slower and hold up resources.  SQL is a optimized for set-based operations and cursors don't leverage that.

One of the many discussions on StackOverflow about Cursors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743183/what-is-wrong-with-cursors